# Commas in map Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dom

I've got:

`bonuses.map(bonus => {
    return '<div class="map-card"> ${bonus.label}: ${bonus.value}</div>';
})`

bonuses is an array of objects like this:

`[{label: 'some lbl', value: 'some val'}]`

and that gives me:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRR98.png)

How i can remove commas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How you are adding bonuses to html?

Comment: it's, render from angular 2 class (component)

Comment: Have you tried the solution that I have posted? Did it worked?

Comment: Yes, i tried. But it doesn't works

Comment: Okay. Can you please replicate it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are setting your html as

```
....innerHTML = bonuses;
```

You will need to set it like

```
....innerHTML = bonuses.join('');
```

Assuming, `bonuses = bonuses.map...`

[A simple working example](https://jsfiddle.net/61cftszn/)